# Displaying, updating and validating values of enum in C++

Tags: c++, enums

```
#include <iostream>

enum SEX {MALE, FEMALE};

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    enum SEX the_sex = MALE;
    return 0;
}
```

How can I display the_sex value on the terminal or console, accept values from the terminal or console to update the value of the_sex and how can I valid the input for the_sex variable?

Comment: What do you want the user to be able to enter? "MALE" or "FEMALE" presumably?

Comment: @BoBTFish Yes, that's fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I accept values from the terminal or console to update the value of the_sex and how can I valid the input for `the_sex` variable?

The input can be represented by whatever you want: an integer (1 for male, 2 for female), a `char` ('M' for male, 'F' for female), a `std::string`. Here's a code example for the `char` version:

```
char in;
std::cin >> in;
switch (in) {
case 'M':
    the_sex = MALE;
    break;
case 'F':
    the_sex = FEMALE;
    break;
default:
    // invalid input
    break;
}
```

or, here's the `std::string` version:

```
std::string in;
std::cin >> in;
        if (in == "MALE") the_sex = MALE;
else    if (in == "FEMALE") the_sex = FEMALE;
else    // invalid input
```

---

> How can I display the_sex value on the terminal or console?

You can simply use a `switch` statement to print out the value of your `SEX` variable:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, SEX the_sex) { 
    switch (the_sex) {
    case MALE:
        os << "MALE";
        break;
    case FEMALE:
        os << "FEMALE";
        break;
    }
    return os;
}
```

Comment: Better to overload operator<< rather than just stick the code in `main` and output to `std::cout`.

Answer (score 2):

To output the value of the enumeration you can write simply

```
std::cout << the_sex;
```

The enumerator will be displayed as an integer value (in this case as 1).

To get and validate a value for the enumeration you can use for example the following loop

```
int e;

do
{
   std::cout << "Enter the sex of the person (0 - FEMALE, 1 - MALE): ";
} while ( std::cin >> e && e != 0 && e != 1 );

if ( std::cin ) the_sex = static_cast<SEX>( e );
```

Comment: What's `cin` in the last line?

Comment: The user could enter the EOF character (CTRL + Z). This line checks whether the user indeed entered a value instead of the EOF.

Comment: @Jefffrey Should be `std::cin` I guess.

Comment: It was my typo. I meant std::cin.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, will you fix it in your answer body?

Comment: I think that there is no need because the question was discussed in the comments.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, I don't even.., but I've fixed that for you.

Answer (score 2):

i'm using a macro for doing this.

```cpp
#define name_num(NAME, ...)                                                    \
class NAME {                                                                   \
                                                                               \
public:                                                                        \
                                                                               \
  enum   enums{NAME_NUM_BEGIN_OF_ENUM_MAP,                                     \
               __VA_ARGS__,                                                    \
               NAME_NUM_END_OF_ENUM_MAP};                                      \
                                                                               \
  using  map_type = boost::bimap<enums, std::string>;                          \
                                                                               \
  NAME(std::string const& str) {                                               \
    std::vector<std::string> v;                                                \
    boost::split(v, str, boost::is_any_of(", "), boost::token_compress_on);    \
    map_type m;                                                                \
                                                                               \
    for(int i=NAME_NUM_BEGIN_OF_ENUM_MAP+1; i!=NAME_NUM_END_OF_ENUM_MAP; i++)  \
      map_.insert(map_type::value_type(static_cast<enums>(i), v[i-1]));        \
  }                                                                            \
                                                                               \
  std::string string(enums val)        { return map_.left.at(val); }           \
                                                                               \
  enums number(std::string const& val) { return map_.right.at(val); }          \
                                                                               \
private:                                                                       \
  map_type map_;                                                               \
} NAME(#__VA_ARGS__)
```

it creates a usual enum list which can be used as usual (e.g. in switches). also it uses boost bimap to map the enums with the coresponding strings.

the first parameter of the macro is the name of the class **and** instance which is used to access the enums and the methods.

finding the enum you use `number` and finding the string you use `string` method. if string (in method number) isn't pointing to a valid enum a `std::out_of_range("bimap<>: invalid key")` will be thrown.

see [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d30c4f8653039bb) example.